# Get a page with PHP from a protected website

Tags: php

There is a website which is accessible to a browser, but can't be accessed via PHP CURL/file_get_contents()

After reading similar topics and answers I've came up with this code that still doesn't work:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'follow_location' => 1,
    'user_agent ' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0",
    'header' => 
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n".
        "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n".
        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n".
        "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n".
        "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n".
        "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n".
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n".
        "Host: www.netcarshow.com"
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$html = file_get_contents("http://www.netcarshow.com", false, $context);
```

The result of this script's execution is ERROR 403: Forbidden. I'm really stuck.

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you spoken to the webmasters of the site to see if there is a misconfiguration at their end, or are you doing this without their permission?

Comment: I have sent them a message but didn't get any reply yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.netcarshow.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    echo curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Returns the 403 error you mentioned.

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.netcarshow.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36");
    echo curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Returns the page.

The only difference is the user agent setting.

It seems that the server is particular about the user agent.

I also tried "My web browser" as the user agent and that returned the page also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that URL is protected by an HTTP basic auth username/password, you're missing the appropriate header:

```
Authorization: Basic [base64-encoded username:password here]
```

e.g.

```
"Authorization" => "Basic " . base64_encode('username:password')
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the URL of the website: http://www.netcarshow.com

It's available via browser without any authentication.

Comment: Ah well... then use something like firebug's net tab or httpfox to examine EXACTLY what your browser is sending when you hit the site. You'll probably find you're missing a header in any case.